# Why can't PHP print xml code with Dublin Core tags?

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I tried to print the content of the file affresco.xml with this php function:

```
<?php $xml=simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/chiesa/affresco.xml") or 
die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->title . "<br>";
echo $xml->description . "<br>";
?>
```

But it didn't print anything. After I tried the same function but I deleted the "dc" from the xml tags and it worked. This is affresco.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<metadata
  xmlns="http://localhost/chiesa/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/chiesa/  
  http://localhost/chiesa/schema.xsd"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

  <title>
    UKOLN
  </title>
  <dc:description>
    UKOLN is a national focus of expertise in digital information
    management. It provides policy, research and awareness services
    to the UK library, information and cultural heritage communities.
   UKOLN is based at the University of Bath.
  </dc:description>


</metadata>
```

How can I print without deleting the "dc" tags?

Comment: `dc` is a namespace in an xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that 'dc' is a namespace, but I can't understand how to print the values from xml with my php function.

Answer (score 3):

To get description, you need find children in 'dc' namespace:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/chiesa/affresco.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
echo $xml->title;
echo $xml->children($ns['dc'])->description;
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/931229)